# DocuSign what are the special fields I can add to Word documents to use via the API

Tags: docusignapi

I am testing the Docusign API and I can send a document to sign and get it signed in the position I want using the SignHere data structure and setting the AnchorString.

I want to add a field for the signed date but what is the format and field name required.  I can't see anywhere that tells me how to type these into a Word document.

I see you can create templates online using Docusign and put in these fields but I don't see how that will work for us.  The document will be dynamically created by our document assembly system and then sent via the Docusign API so I need to build in the fields at that point when I add the signature anchor string.

So what is the Word document special field format and list of Docusign available fields please?

Also it would be good to know how to insert a field to ask the signer to enter some text.  Any entry box.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a nice elegant solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Salesforce to send out these documents, the DocuSign CLM product supports template codes in Word. See [docs.](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/SpringCM-Document-Generation-Word-Template-Merge-Tags)

Otherwise, you can only specify locations of fields (tabs) in the Word doc. This is done via *anchor strings* also known as *auto-place fields*. [Docs.](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/AutoPlace-New-DocuSign-Experience)

Placing the anchor strings in your Word doc is the first step. For the second step, I recommend that you create a DocuSign *template* by using the DocuSign web tool. Then, when you send the document via the API, you combine it with the template. Or better, you can insert the Word document into the template itself.

The advantage of this technique is that your business users, with the right instructions, can update the template by themselves.

An alternative is for the DocuSign API request to specify the document and the various fields (tabs) that should be included in the document for the signers.

### Added

Two other options:

1. Create your source documents as HTML documents. You can include special tags to indicate different types of DocuSign fields. You can also indicate sections of documents that can be expanded/closed by the signer. [HTML field documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/request-params).

   This is the best approach, IMHO.
2. Create your source documents as PDF Forms with form fields. DocuSign can then transform the PDF form fields into DocuSign form fields. There are limitations. [Docs.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs#tab-placement-method-3-pdf-form-field-transformation)

Comment: We are not using Salesforce.  We have a large and complex legal application that will assemble its own documents that may be many pages in varying length due to many optional paragraphs.

The users sending probably won't be going into Docusign at all so they won't be able to create templates and I'm not sure how they could align with what our document assembly produces.  I had assumed I could add extra fields to be filled in by each recipient via the API just like I can with the SignHere data structure and using unique anchor strings in the document.  Is this not the case?